# Python push button and thickbox properties

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

Can i get a hand on the following:

i am using an imported and converted (to py) file from Qt in my program. 
In my first window i created a push button: i would like to: Once clicking on this button it leads me to my second window(created with QT also).

This main window has also 2 thickboxes.
Car1
car2

The second windows as a set of 2 comboboxes.

if i thick car1 i would like each combobox to allow me selecting only (speed1,weight1,fuel1)
if i thick car2 i would like each combobox to allow me selecting only (speed2,weight2,fuel2)
if i thick car1&car2 i would like each combobox to allow me selecting  (speed1,weight1,fuel1,speed2,weight2,fuel2)

Can i have a kind advice or code example?

thanks in advance,

06

I am at the start and new using python:

```
#10----------------------------------------------
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys
from os.path import expanduser
import os
import shlex

#import Converted Python UI File
from W0 import Ui_MainWindow


class Main(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)



    #30-----------------------------------------------------------
    # Connect the pushbutton i am unable to get any action from the button
    pushbutton = QtGui.QPushButton('Popup Button')


    def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Main()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

    main()
```

Comment: Please include the code you've already written, and indicate which part of it is causing a problem for you

Comment: Sorry I messed the indent trying to fix it. Can anyone help?